# Показать в edit control текст с заданной строки

Tags: winapi, gui

В winapi есть сообщение [EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getfirstvisibleline), с помощью которого можно получить для многострочного едит контрола первую отображаемую в нём строку. Сообщения EM_SETFIRSTVISIBLELINE в winapi нет. В связи с этим есть вопрос: как сделать обратную операцию, прокрутить едит контрол так, чтобы первой видимой строкой стала строка с заданным номером?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл следующее для себя решение:

```
// получить строку
int line = SendMessage(hWnd, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);

// сделать какую-нибудь операцию вставки, меняющую положение Scroll Bar'а
// ...

// перемотать вверх
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_VSCROLL, SB_TOP, 0);

// перемотать на line строк вниз
SendMessage(hWnd, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, line);
```

Comment: Да. Но мотать наверх не обязательно. Можно просто так:   
       int Line= SendMessage(hwnd, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);
       SendMessage(hwnd, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, NewLineNumber-Line);

Comment: Но ведь, насколько я понимаю, EM_LINESCROLL проматывает только вниз. Или в Вашем примере передаётся отрицательное число в lParam для возможности промотки вверх?

Comment: Да, EM_LINESCROLL работает с отрицательными числами. По крайней мере, у меня.